# Loader Image on Synchronous call - Rest Api SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, ajax, jquery-ajax

Stuck with "Loader" while deleting items. I have a set of items to delete and need to display a loader image while deleting. But, for some reason, i'm not able to solve this. I have came across different solutions and implemented it hoping it will solve the issue. But, no luck. Below were the solutions i implemented.

---

1. AjaxStart, AjaxStop methods
2. SetTimeout(function(){},0);
3. jQuery.ajaxSetup({beforeSend:function(),complete()})
4. fadeIn,Fadeout methods

   ---

I have used the below code as synchronous...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('#callLoader').hide();

    $('#btndelete').click(function(){
        $('#callLoader').show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('12kListItems')/items?$top=9999",
                    },beforeSend: function () { 
                    $('#callLoader').show();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var items = data.d.results;
                    var counter = 0;        
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                        if(data.d.results[i].Id != undefined){
                            //storage.push(data.d.results[i].Id);
                            $('#DisplayCounter').text(i);
                        }               
                     }
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#callLoader').hide();
                    },1000);
                },
                async:false,
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            })
        ;}, 0);

        $('#callLoader').hide();            

    });
});
```

"callLoader" is a Div tag

Comment: can you explain what is happening now, and what exactly you want? I am not sure what you are using `setTimeOut` for both the occurrence. If you can tell the exact behavior may be we can help.

Comment: @ThinkB4Code : Currently, the ('#callLoader').show(); is being executed but, it is not displaying the loader image due to synchronous operation. Without showing the image, the operation is performed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification, I had modified your code, can you check below in answer and try out the code.

Answer (score 1):

### Asynchronous Solution

You can take advantage of the fact that the `$.ajax()` method returns [jqXHR objects that implement the Promise interface](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#callLoader').hide();

  $('#btndelete').click(function(){
    $('#callLoader').show();

    $.ajax({
      url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('12kListItems')/items?$top=9999"
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      var items = data.d.results;
      var counter = 0;        
      for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
        if(data.d.results[i].Id !== undefined){
          //storage.push(data.d.results[i].Id);
          $('#DisplayCounter').text(i);
        }               
      }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
    }).always(function(){
      $('#callLoader').hide();
    });
  });

});
```

---

### Synchronous Solution:

The jQuery documentation on ajax indicates that setting the `async` to `false` will allow your call to be done synchronously:

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR
>   ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete
>   callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR
>   object such as jqXHR.done()

The following code should accomplish what you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#callLoader').hide();

  $('#btndelete').click(function(){
    $('#callLoader').show();

    $.ajax({
      url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('12kListItems')/items?$top=9999",
      async: false,
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        var counter = 0;        
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
          if(data.d.results[i].Id !== undefined){
            //storage.push(data.d.results[i].Id);
            $('#DisplayCounter').text(i);
          }               
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
      },
      complete: function(){
        $('#callLoader').hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. But, i'm using the Rest Api ajax call as Synchronous. Your suggested code works as Async. Any other alternative ways ?

Comment: @ShandeepAM I've added a synchronous solution to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ajax events](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) to achieve your goal.
Use ***beforeSend*** & ***complete*** event in Ajax.

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('12kListItems')/items?$top=9999",
    },
    beforeSend: function () { 
            $('#callLoader').show();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $('#callLoader').hide();
    },
```

Comment: This will successfully work on Async:true condition. But, does not work on Async:false condition. Any other alternatives ?

Comment: in that case theChrisKent synchronous solution will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had updated your code. There was a problem in your code that after `url: .....,` the next line contains end of ajax option object i.e. `}, before...`. The `}` here ends the ajax options because of that, you were having problem.

Try the below code and let us know if this is working or not.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#btndelete').click(function(){
        $('#callLoader').show();

        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('12kListItems')/items?$top=9999",
            success: function (data) {
                var items = data.d.results;
                var counter = 0;        
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                    if(data.d.results[i].Id != undefined){
                        //storage.push(data.d.results[i].Id);
                        $('#DisplayCounter').text(i);
                    }               
                }

                $('#callLoader').hide();
            },
            async:false,
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                $('#callLoader').hide();
            }
        });          

    });
});
```

Comment: I have already implemented the same code. the problem is the list has 12k items. So, it created the problem. Now, i have used JSOM as alternative solution. Works Awesome ! Thanks much for your suggestions.